# Moving a specific user from the admin localgroup to power users in BATCH

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have around 80 Windows 7 machines in my office that were been set up in the past with Administrator accounts. I would like to change them to Power Users so they can still do certain things without authorization from us, but not change system settings.

I want to push a batch file to all machines at the same time initiating this, but I don't know how to identify the user's account specifically to change, as they're all named differently.

For example, `net user` outputs this:

```
Administrator              Guest                <userofmachine>
```

I would like to pull  from that output somehow and proceed with changing their localgroup. I'm used to doing this on Linux, but unfamiliar with this aspect of Windows.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: A couple of notes First, [the Power Users group doesn't do anything anymore](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771990.aspx). Second, local Administrators group membership can be [dictated by Group Policy](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20402.active-directory-group-policy-restricted-groups.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info about Power Users! Also, as much as I would like to do this through AD, it's not the system we run on. I'll probably push this through our Webroot Admin Panel.

Comment: So the question is, what do you really need for users to be able to do?

Comment: I need them to not be able to do as much. As admins, they can install and disable whatever they want, which caused problems before I got here and is continuing to do so. I really just need to move them all to Users. It's getting the script to choose the account on its own that I can't figure out.

Comment: So you want to remove all accounts from Administrators group except for some accounts. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. We have a local admin account that we log into for maintenance, for example. We want to keep that the way it is.

Comment: Be aware that once a user is in the Administrators group, removing them may potentially break stuff, because all of their files will belong to Administrators rather than them.  The permissions ought to be OK, so ownership might not matter, but you probably shouldn't roll this out all at once.  Try just a few users first and make sure there aren't too many problems.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments, I think this is what you need to delete a user from the local admin group.  They should already be in the users group since they are users.

net localgroup administrators UserNameGoesHere /delete

If you want to clear out the group completely, something like this should work

for /F %i in ('net localgroup groupname') do net localgroup groupname %i /delete

If you just want to list all the members of the group, so you don't kill your local admin account from the group too, try

net localgroup "group name goes here"

Comment: Correct. I just need to be able to grab the right user name.

Comment: Added a couple things to my answer that hopefully help you in your task.

Comment: It does! So if I have two admin accounts, "svc.it" and "user", what would remove "user" from administrators but not "svc.it"?

Comment: Change out UserNameGoesHere from that first command line in my answer to user and that should do it.

Comment: I figured as much. "user" was just an example though. The account to change is typically the name of the person using the machine, so it's different for every user.
In reality, that account could be "Bob" or "Jill" or "Harry".

Comment: Can I just somehow store the account name in a variable as a string and then call the variable in the command you gave me? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: One solution might be to generate the list, then have it delete every account except the one you want to keep.  I haven't tried this, but what about trying the line to clear out the entire group, then do a   net localgroup group_name UserLoginName /add   to add back in the accounts you want?  but I don't know if that would work since you'd probably kill the account you're running the command as if you're doing this to administrators, so the last add might not work.  But might be worth a shot with a less important user group.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I didn't want to ruin my own permissions so that it didn't run. I'll see what I can do in regards to getting a piece of 'net user' output into a variable. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know powershell, but maybe you do and this will help (although it's for ad accounts not local accounts) http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/06/18/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-set-of-users-from-the-local-administrators-group.aspx.  Hope my answer above and comments helped.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to remove all the accounts from the group (this will fail for Administrator, BTW) and then add back in the ones you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the EnforceLocalAdmin.vbs script from this article:

[Windows IT Pro: Enforcing the Membership of the Administrators Group](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/enforcing-membership-administrators-group)

For example:

```
EnforceLocalAdmin.vbs "Administrator,DesktopSupport,SysAdmin"
```

This command specifies that only the three named accounts are members of the local Administrators group. The script does not depend on the group being named "Administrators" because it determines the group using the SID (S-1-5-32-544).